Using Flow, is there a way to update a single field only for all records in a collection of records
I want to update a single field in a collection of Account records. In the Update Records Element, the only option that accepts a collection is 'Use the IDs and all field values from a record or record collection; and this does not allow you to specify which fields to update. 
Processing time would be short and the likely hood of another transaction updating a field on the record is low, but I want to avoid the risk if possible.
Documentation for the Lock Record Action says:

The lock record action only works for workflow-enabled or
approval-enabled records

which confuses me as all examples I have seen using this functionality seem to ignore this restriction.
Would looping at my collection of Account records from Get Records Element and locking each record be the way to go?
Does a lock have to be explicitly removed at the end of the Flow?
Also trying to find information on removing locks, if a Flow goes pear shaped and I need to as Admin remove locks from records.

If you want to update a single field in a collection of Account records, then you can perform the following steps, in this order, in your flow;
What we are doing?
We are fetching a collection of Account records. Then we will, loop through each Account and assign this Account's Id and other fields that we are interested in updating to a variable (which is of type Account record). So this variable only holds, Id (which is mandatory, if we wish to update) and other fields that we are trying to update. 
Then add this variable to another variable (which holds a List of Records, think of this as a collection of records).
Now, in our collection, we would have all of account record variable to update, which we can update using the update records element and pass in this collection.

I have explained two ways to achieve this, the first way is abit more customisable, in the sense, you can fetch all fields for an object and then mutate only the ones you want to and maybe you would want to use the other fields to do some other logic in the flow.
The second approach, is very specific to what you want to achieve in a simpler way, though this only saves us the creation of 2 new variables and 1 additional line in the Assignment element logic.

First Approach:

Get the collection of Account records (using get records)
Create a new resource of type 'Variable', choose the Data Type to be 'Record' and check the 'Allow multiple values (collection)' checkbox.
Create another new resource with the follow settings

Then loop through each of your account from step 1 and process them in this way.

Finally use this 'accountList' (variable created), with the updateRecords element.


With these approach, you can only choose to update the fields you want. Make sure, all of the records have Id populated.
Another way:
Another way to achieve this in much simpler flow structure, is that; First let's declare a simple scenario.
"I would want to change all of my Accounts Rating to 'Hot' and Account Source   to 'Web'"

Fetch Account records, and specify only the fields, we wish to update. In this case, Rating and Account Source

Perform loop on the collection obtained from Step 1, pair with an assignment element to edit/mutate the fields data.

Use update records element and pass back the same collection obtained from Step 1. Since the data has been edited/mutated in Step 2.



Hi Prem,
Thanks for your response.
So, on the Get Records element the 'how to store data' choice 'Choose fields and let Salesforce do the rest' lets you work with the data the same as how APEX is documented in the following link, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_insert_update.htm.

@JulianC It is the same as SOQL query, where you only fetch the fields that you are interested in, compared to fetching all the fields.
